# How to use Font Awesome 6 icons?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-6

I've used the Font Awesome icons before (previous version). Back then, I used a CDN like below in my HTML. But now I can't find it anymore. Is there any change on how to use them?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">
```

Comment: From their [document page](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/use-kit), they said _The Font Awesome CDN does not support v6 so your best bet is to use a Kit._ It seems they don't want you to use CDN but yes, you can use CDN link in the answer below.

Comment: @vee Please be careful with references like "below". Currently (at least by my sorting) you are endorsing a somewhat improveable answer...

Comment: @Yunnosch It's comment section and there are characters **limited**. There are at least 2 answers currently using CDN. So, it is not so hard to just scroll down and try those links. This should be easy to understand and shouldn't be the point.

Comment: Font Awesome continues to get shadier, it started as a crowd-funded CDN project and has morphed into an opt-out email marketing ploy which actually hurts web performance, because clients can't store the same CDN asset in their browser cache.

Comment: I think they made v6 free now available again via their CDN, just not v6 Pro. Their website is not consistent in the wording, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To use the new free [Font Awesome 6](https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons?m=free), you can again use the CDN (if that's your preference) like the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
```

Then, use icons in your HTML as follows.

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can i enquire some websites use unicode to point to the icon? Why would they do that if it is possible to use name such as fa-house.  Which is a better practice?

Comment: If you want to use insert an icon in CSS using `::before` or `::after` with `content`, then you need the unicode. The names are the best option for HTML.

Comment: @NickWills Using class names like fa-house is generally easier and more readable. It allows you to quickly understand which icon is being used just by looking at the class name. This is usually the preferred method for most developers.

Answer (score 8):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" />
```

add this link in your head of the html file,
and
use a font awesome link for an icon. if the link is like

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

you want to use it in your page inside of
<a
tag like

```
<a><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro</a>
```

Comment: downvoted, because your link has a href to font-awesome version 4.7.0

Comment: i am very sorry i will update the link for font-awesome version 6.0.0

Answer (score 3):

It is worth flagging here that whilst yes, the CDN is possible (and you can also download the files and host them locally (https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts))  these fonts are a **limited subset** of the "Free plan" version.

For example, `fa-envelope-o` will come up as a Free icon but if you look in the webfonts or all.css this is not included. However it *is* if you signup for the free plan (https://fontawesome.com/plans). They will send you a .js link to include however you are limited to 10k connections per month. Which for most sites will be suitable and opens up a much larger selection than the CDN option.

I have nothing to do with FA - just figured out why downloading and hosting the fonts yourself is pointless and you might as well just signup!

Comment: 10K is small for my blog, is there any alternative with CDN option?

Comment: I'm no expert but I think if 10k isn't sufficient you'd need to pay. Its $99 a year so not horrendous - I guess it depends how many you need. Or alternatively find a different free icon provider.

Comment: It's turned into an absolutely ridiculous project, this is what happens when we support independent creators apparently... at this point, I'm rooting for Google's Material Icons to continue expanding as rapidly as it has been lately.

Comment: It looks like `fa-envelope-o` is still available, they just renamed it: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/upgrade-from-v4

You can see it is available as `<i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i>`.