# problems showing icons from fontawesome on my button

Tags: angular-material, font-awesome

I have this

```
<mat-card>
 <mat-card-title>{{title}}</mat-card-title>
 <mat-card-subtitle>{{subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
 <mat-card-actions>
 <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' style='width:80px' (click)='onBack()'>
  <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>
 </button>
 <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' style='width:80px' (click)='verMes()'>
  <i class='fa fa-solid fa-calendar-days'></i>
 </button>
 <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' style='width:80px'      (click)='verQuincena()'>
  <i class='fa fa-solid fa-calendar-week'></i>
 </button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

But only see this

[image]

Where are my calendar views?

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: which font awesome version are you using and how are you importing the styles?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you are using *Font Awesome 4* in your project. According to [list of icon in FA4](https://fontawesome.com/v4/icons/), the 2 last icon was not supported.

> New in Font Awesome 5 is the `fas` prefix, Font Awesome 4 uses `fa`.
>
> The s in `fas` stands for *solid*, and some icons also have a
> *regular* mode, specified by using the prefix `far`.
> -- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp)

Two icon you was used is from [Font Awesome 6](https://fontawesome.com/search). So that to use this in your project, you should update your package to at least [version 6 of FA](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/).

*Tip: Using Chrome DevTools and you can get class name of icon was used in webpage (In this case is Font Awesome).*

**See more:**

- [Font Awesome icons are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/font-awesome-icons-are-not-working-i-have-included-all-required-files)
- [How to use Font Awesome 6 icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201741/how-to-use-font-awesome-6-icons)